# Inject custom code in standard application

Tags: c#, ninject, unity-container

We have a standard application in our company.
Now I want to inject some custom assemblies in the application.

Normally if you have a ninject kernel or unity container, you can get the implementation like below:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
DealerService myServ = new DealerService(kernel.Get<IDealerController>());
```

DealerService:

```
public partial class DealerService : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly IDealerController Controller;

    public DealerService(IDealerController controller)
    {
        Controller = controller;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Process();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        Controller.GetDealerDetails(5);
    }
}
```

DealerController interface

```
public interface IDealerController
{
    Dealer GetDealerDetails(int dealerId);
}
```

Implementation of the dealer controller:

```
public class DealerController : IDealerController
{
    public Dealer GetDealerDetails(int dealerId)
    {     
        throw new NotImplementedException("This is a custom error thrown from the controller implementation");
    }
}
```

Now the thing is that I don't want that the standard application knows about the custom assemblies. The dealerservice is a workflow activity so that is found dynamically by workflow foundation. The problem is that the injected `DealerController` is empty...
How can I inject the implementation of the `IDealerController` in my standardapplication without the line `kernel.Get<IDealerController>()`.

If you use Ninject with the ninject MVC 3  nuget package, the implementation is injected in the constructor of the mvc controller without calling the `kernel.Get<IDealerController>()`.

**Edit:**
Added the module with as assembly name Ninject.Extensions.Controllers.Module so the Module is found by naming convention. This is described in the Ninject [documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel). This works in my MVC application.

```
public class ControllersModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {            
        this.Bind<IDealerController>().To<DealerController>();            
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of `Modules` and the `Kernel.Load` mechanism (and can you use the teminology from that context to clarify your question please)?

Comment: I added my module above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inject the `IDealerController` implementation into `DealerService`, you will also have to let Ninject to manage the instantiation of the `DealerService`.

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IDealerController>.To<DefaultDealerController>(); //.InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<DealerService>().ToSelf(); //.InSingletonScope();
DealerService myServ = kernel.Get<DealerService>();
```

To dynamically load Ninject configuration you can use [modules](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel) approach and `kernel.Load("*.dll")` method. If you will have multiple implementations of some interface, you should also specify which one should be used with the help of the [conditional binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding).

```
kernel.Bind<IDealerController>
      .To<SpecialDealerController>()
      .When(x=> SpecialConditionIsMet());
```

Comment: If forgot to instantiate the DealerService itself with Ninject. Line 3 and 4 of your code did the trick for me. 
Now I have a following question. What if the DealerService is an activity of Workflow Foundation? So the standard application is starting the workflow that the user has designed. In that workflow he used my custom wf activity (DealerService) and that DealerService must instantiate the DealerController. Should I create the instance of the workflow invoker by Ninject to get this to work?

Comment: See for this my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498403/dependency-injection-in-custom-workflow-activity

Comment: I'm not familiar with WF. Try to read through the Ninject wf extension wiki and get the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

You can have different `Module` inheriting from `NinjectModule` in each assembly:

```
public class WarriorModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load() 
    {
        Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
        Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
    }
}
```

Then use the `Kernel` to dynamically load all modules from all assemblies in `AppDomain`:

```
kernel.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

All examples are taken from [Ninject documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel).